# Add explicit dependencies for jQuery (Mobile) widget/plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, dependencies, requirejs

I cannot figure out an elegant solution for the following problem.

I've created a small jQuery Mobile widget that enriches an input field with stuff related to amounts and currencies. To not reinvent the wheel, I've included *autoNumeric.js* plugin. For example, within the `_create` method I'm doing the following.

```
/**
 * autoNumeric.js required (https://github.com/BobKnothe/autoNumeric)
 */
(function($, window, document, undefined) {     
    "use strict";

    $.widget("mobile.amountinput", $.mobile.textinput, {

        // other code here

        _create : function() {

            // other code here

            $element.autoNumeric('init');

            $element.focus(function(event) {
                var o = { aDec: ',', aSep : '.', pSign: 's', aSign: '' };
                $element.autoNumeric('update', o); 
            });

            $element.blur(function(event) {
                var o = { aDec: ',', aSep : '.', pSign: 's', aSign: ' €' };
                $element.autoNumeric('update', o); 
            });
        }
    });

    $.mobile.document.bind("pagecreate create", function(e) {
        $.mobile.input.prototype.enhanceWithin(e.target, true);
    });

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

*autoNumeric.js* is loaded through *require.js* but I would like to make the dependency explicit (like within *require.js* module definition). In this way, I can be sure that *autoNumeric.js* exists and has been imported correctly.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work. Replace the `'autonumeric'` dependency in the list of dependencies passed to `define` with whatever is appropriate in your case. I'm not sure why you need `undefined` in the list of parameters but I've kept it there.

```
(function (factory) {
    // If in an AMD environment, define() our module, else use the
    // jQuery global.
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define(['jquery', 'autonumeric'], function ($) {
            factory($, window, document);
        });
    else
        factory($, window, document);
}(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    $.widget("mobile.amountinput", $.mobile.textinput, {

        // other code here

        _create : function() {

            // other code here

            $element.autoNumeric('init');

            $element.focus(function(event) {
                var o = { aDec: ',', aSep : '.', pSign: 's', aSign: '' };
                $element.autoNumeric('update', o);
            });

            $element.blur(function(event) {
                var o = { aDec: ',', aSep : '.', pSign: 's', aSign: ' €' };
                $element.autoNumeric('update', o);
            });
        }
    });

    $.mobile.document.bind("pagecreate create", function(e) {
        $.mobile.input.prototype.enhanceWithin(e.target, true);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll come back with a feedback. `undefined` is passed to prevent a redefinition for it.